# find longest string in with criteria - excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two columns Item and ID - refer to the Sample Table. I need a formula in Excel to determine the longest (based on simple length of ID) per item.

Here is what I am trying to extract from the sample table:

```
Item 1 ABCDABC
Item 2 XXXYZ
```

I tried index match combination:

```
=INDEX("ID column",MATCH(MAX(LEN("ID column")),LEN("ID column"),0),MATCH("Item 1" , "Item Column",0))
```

with ctrl+shift+enter

here are the results:

```
Item 1 ABCDABC
Item 2 #REF!
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
Sample Table
Item        ID 
Item 1      ABC
Item 1      ABCD
Item 1      ABCDA
Item 1      ABCDAB
Item 1      ABCDABC
Item 2      X
Item 2      XX
Item 2      XXX
Item 2      XXXY
Item 2      XXXYZ
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will return the correct index:

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$11,MATCH(MAX(INDEX(LEN($B$2:$B$11)*($A$2:$A$11=D3),)),INDEX(LEN($B$2:$B$11)*($A$2:$A$11=D3),),0))
```

[image]

Comment: Beautiful!!! worked like magic! I am using this site for the first time. How do I give credit to Scott Craner.

Comment: @BrianAtakhodjaev, the answer which helped the most should be accepted using the tick mark to the left of the answer. When you have 15+ reputation you can also upvote any questions and answers which you find useful.

Comment: @BrianAtakhodjaev click on the check mark by the answer that you ended up using.

Answer (score 2):

A PivotTable is perfect for this, because it will handle ties.

1. Turn your source data into an Excel Table

[image]

2. Add a new column to your source data, and use the LEN function to
   return the length of each item. You only need to add the formula to the top row, and Excel will copy it down using Table notation:

[image]

3. Make a PivotTable out of that Table, and put Item and ID in the ROWS
   pane and put Length into the Values pane:

[image]

4. Right-click on one of the cells in the Sum of Length PivotField, and
   change the aggregation to MAX:

[image]

5. Click the ID filter dropdown, and select Values Filter > Top 10...

[image]

6. In the dialog box, change the 10 in the to a 1 and click OK:

[image]

***BING!***

[image]

...and if two IDs within the same category have the exact same length, the PivotTable shows you both of them:

[image]

Comment: No prob. Don't forget to accept one of the answers...both approaches work fine, so it's really a case of 'horses for courses' as the saying goes.

Comment: how do I accept the answer? I have pressed "answer is useful" sign in both cases. Will that do?